# Faye server logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, faye

How to enable logging on Faye server?
I am tying:

`Faye::Logging.log_level = :debug
 Faye.logger = lambda { |m| puts m }`

I am getting the following error:

```
/faye.ru:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `log_level=' for Faye::Logging:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I use Faye version **1.1.2** on Ruby on Rails **4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log_level` has been deprecated in that version of Faye.

You should set the log level on a `Logger` object and then pass it to `Faye.logger`.

Comment: Please give example, I don't understand how make this.

Comment: If we use Ruby version of Faye. Then we need to set Faye.logger to be a logger object, for example:
`Faye.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`
Anything that conforms to the Logger interface should work. Thanks **brito**